# Leaflet Realtime: store geoJSON data in variable

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Probably an easy question:

I use leaflet-realtime to visualize incoming geo-referenced reports on a map (mysql-> PHP-> AJAX -> geoJSON). https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime

```
var map = L.map('map'),
    realtime = L.realtime({
        url: 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/',
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: 'json'
    }, {
        interval: 3 * 1000
    }).addTo(map);

realtime.on('update', function() {
    map.fitBounds(realtime.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 3});
});
```

Ok, now I am a little bit confused, because I would like store the requested geojason-data in a variable to display the the messages additional in a realtime HTML-Table generated with java-script. Who can give me a little hint?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The `update` event can provide a hash of all the features in the layer - you could use this to generate your table.

```
realtime.on('update', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(realtime.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 3});
    // Do something here with e.features
});
```

Comment: Thank you peeebeee. I think, this tip will help.